# TSQL CASE unexpectedly processing multiple THEN statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a simple SQL CASE statement that I am trying to interpret the datatype of a variable and then converting it to said format.  I have the following sample:

```
  DECLARE @P1 varchar(10) = '2';

  SELECT CASE 1 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(@P1) THEN (CAST(@P1 AS INT)) 
    WHEN ISDATE(@P1) THEN (CAST(@P1 AS DateTime)) 
    ELSE 'N' END AS Test2P1
```

I would expect it to return an integer value of 2.  However, this is what I get.

Test2P1

1900-01-03 00:00:00.000

However, if I modify the code to just display a character instead of CASTING the variable, I get a different result:

```
  DECLARE @P1 varchar(10) = '2';


  SELECT CASE 1 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(@P1) THEN 'I' 
    WHEN ISDATE(@P1) THEN 'D'
    ELSE 'N' END AS Test2P1
```

Then I get a result of:  I

Taking this experiment one step further, if I leave the first test returning an 'I' but casting the date, then I get an error:

```
  DECLARE @P1 varchar(10) = '2';

  SELECT CASE 1 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(@P1) THEN 'I'
    WHEN ISDATE(@P1) THEN (CAST(@P1 AS DateTime)) 
    ELSE 'N' END AS Test2P1

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

It appears that SQL is evaluating multiple instances of THEN statements.  However, the ISDATE expression does NOT return true.  I am stumped.

In my research, I came across this article [SQL Performance] (https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)  What he is saying in this article makes complete sense.  But I do not see where it applies in this situation as I am never changing the value of the variable.

I have also wrapped my CASE statement in COALESCE(), but it does not appear to help.  I wouldn't have expected it to, but I found multiple articles referencing this as a solution to similar problems.  This seems like a very simple CASE statement, but I do not know where I am going wrong.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your case expression is strange. Why CASE 1? That shouldn't even compile, let alone run. But the bigger issue is you are mixing datatypes in your case expression. You can't change datatypes in a single column for every row. The **entire** column MUST be a single datatype. When it encounters things like you have it will do an implicit conversion to the datatype with higher precedence, hence the error message you see.

Comment: Logically thinking through, you can't have a column defined with multiple data types, so my guess is that the query processor is trying to find the best data type to use for all the data in the column and failing to do so.

Comment: @SeanLange I think it's a strange way of writing instead of `when isnumeric(@p1) = 1 then...when isdate(@p1) = 1 then...`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Oh I see....what a strange way to write that. I have to admit I have never seen anything like that and am shocked it actually works. But I just tested it and it does. Talk about a confusing pattern.

Comment: @SeanLange I also thought it shouldn't compile at first, but then it hit me - if you can do `case @var when value then...when othervalue then...` why shouldn't you be able to do `case value when method then... when othermethod then...`? Not that I would ever think of writing such a thing (even if I know it's possible) since I think it's terrible for readability, but it's nice to know the option is out there.

Comment: @SeanLange @Zohar Peled Along the lines of SELECT TOP `99999999 .... ORDER BY` in a view to created an ordered view...  (which is officially unsupported by Microsoft)

Comment: @squillman and also just a waist of time since a view, much like a table, is unordered. That's the reason you get an error if you try to use `order by` without `top` or `for xml/json` in a view in the first place. Adding `TOP 999999` just makes the error go away, it doesn't make the view ordered. (btw, there's also `top 100%`, but that is just as useless.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I would typically agree with you.  However, we have a third party product that can query SQL Server to import data.  You have to manually add the components of the query into text boxes and it generates the SQL.  There is no ORDER BY text box.....  In some circumstances the product requires ordered results.  This was our (--terrible--) hack to get around that.  I want go gouge my eyes out every time I see it.

Comment: @Bill BTW, `ISNUMERIC` will return 1 even for values that will fail the cast to int...

Comment: Even with a view like that it is still not guaranteed to return rows in that order. That merely is used to determine which rows from the base table(s) would be in the view. And even more ridiculous would be if you had two views like that each with their own view. What would the order be then? If you are using a view like that it is only dumb luck they get returned in that order. It will break at some point. There is 1 and only 1 way to order a result set, that is to use an order by on the final query.

Comment: Aside: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't think of a good reason to do this, you could force the case expression to return `sql_variant`, which can store multiple different types, eg:

```
 DECLARE @P1 varchar(10) = '2';

  SELECT CASE 1 
    when 0 then cast(null as sql_variant)
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(@P1) THEN (CAST(@P1 AS INT)) 
    WHEN ISDATE(@P1) THEN (CAST(@P1 AS DateTime)) 
    ELSE 'N' END AS Test2P1
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 6):

`DateTime` has a higher datatype precedence in SQL Server than `INT` does, so your whole CASE is getting cast as `DATETIME`.  You can only return data of a single datatype in one column, thus the need for datatype precedence.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the MSDN article showing precedence.

Comment: This makes sense.  The intent behind this is I am separating out a comma delimited string into individual columns (which I have successfully done).  However, the bigger picture which I did not post here is that the string would be the same for each row, thus would have the same datatype all of the way down.  I guess the better idea is to process all of that prior to adding it to my select statement.  The linked help me understand some more of WHY it is happening.  You guys are awesome!